# Condition return of model function by value of Summation Expression

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am building an Abstract optimization model with Pyomo in Python. I have a model variable (model.x) which is indexed with 4 sets. To build my objective function, i build 5 different terms with Python, then add them up, and return them. 
I use functions to return some values for the objective function. These functions use SumExpressions. I then want to check if the calculated expression is > 0 mod 2, but this is not working.

I already tried to replace my if-clause with an assert, but its not doing what i inially wanted it to do. I also tried to somehow retrieve the value of the expression with value(), but this will raise an error since the varaibles don't have values yet.

This is the function i call from the objective rule:

```py
def sportGleichzeitig(model,k,z):
    sport = sum(model.x[k,l,"SportM",z] for l in model.Lehrer) + 
    sum(model.x[k,l,"SportW",z] for l in model.Lehrer)

    if sport % 2 > 0 :
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

This is the part of the objective rule referring to the function

```py
sport = model.sportweight * sum(sportGleichzeitig(model,k,z) for k in model.Klassen for z in model.Zeitslots)
```

So i want to weigh in sport whenever "SportW" and "SportM" is at the same time. This code raises the following exception:

```py
TypeError at /optimierung/
unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'SumExpression' and 'int'
```

Is there a way of doing this with Pyomo?

Comment: Apparently, `sport` is of type `SumExpression` which does not implement the modulo operation. What methods does this class offer?

Comment: I thought about that already and tried finding something in Pyomos Docs
https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pyomo/docconversion/pyomo.pdf
But i found it hard to find any answers in here

Comment: Could it be the case that Pyomo does not support modulo on unevaluated SumExpressions?
Ofc you can evaluate sport and then apply modulo, but this will slow down your computations ...

Comment: This could be the case. How would i evaluate sport? whenever i treid it raised errors...any other suggestions what i could do?

Comment: According to page 240, a SumExpression provides the method `_apply_operation` to compute its result.
PS: providing a small, but runable example would be really helpful.

Comment: Rewriting your model with integer variables and one surplus continuous variable that takes the value of your modulo operation could be a good way of going arround your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most optimization frameworks / formulations, you're not allowed to use the kind of functions you are trying to use (mod / if). Particularly in LP programs.
An if statement can be expressed through a binary variable in MILP / MINLP formulation, mod is harder (it is periodically non-differentiable).
I'm not sure if Pyomo supports the mod operator at all, but my guess it that it doesn't.
Even if it does, you first need to make sure the solver you are going to use can solve this kind of problem (mixed integer non-linear with non-differentiable points).

If `sportGleichzeitig` is associated to a cost, and therefore you expect the solver to minimize it, one way to express this in a MILP formulation is the following:

- `a`: non-negative integer variable (auxiliary)
- `sportGleichzeitig`: binary **variable**
- `sport >= a * 2`
- `sport <= a * 2 + sportGleichzeitig * 2`

This way:

- if `mod(sport,2) == 0`, `a` will be `sport/2` and `sportGleichzeitig` will be 0
- if `mod(sport,2) != 0`, `a` will be `sport // 2` and `sportGleichzeitig` will be 1

The risk is that `sportGleichzeitig` is 1 even though `mod(sport,2) == 0`.
This is why as mentioned above this only works if `sportGleichzeitig` is part of your objective function and is associated to a cost, that why the model will always try to minimize it if it's possible.